# Swagger is working only on Internet Explorer mode which is running on Nginx

Tags: nginx, .net-core, swagger

A Web API/Swagger is running on Nginx. Enabled the basic authentication. But the Swagger is working only on Internet Explorer mode in Edge browser and not on other browsers.

```
auth_basic  "Restricted";
auth_basic_user_file   /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
```

When we comment out the above lines (`auth_basic` and `auth_basic_user_file`), we are able to open the Swagger in any browser without the authentication.

Help me in fixing this issue. This Swagger should be working on all the browsers with authentication.